# Which one is the correct definition of natural norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

In the definition 2 of [Normal Subgroup Reconstruction and Quantum Computation Using Group Representations](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/HRT.stoc00.pdf), the authors have defined the natural norm of a matrix as follows.

> The natural norm of the matrix $A$ is given by $||A||$ such that
>   $||A||^2 = Tr (A^\dagger A)$.

On the other hand, in the lecture note [Norms of Vectors and Matrices](http://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms40390F11/sec7-1.pdf), 
the same concept is defined as follows.

If $||\cdot||$ is a vector norm, the induced (or natural) matrix norm is given by $$||A|| =\max_{|| x|| = 1} ||A  x||$$

**My question:**

Which one is the correct definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first matrix norm is called the Frobenius norm, it's natural as in that it's the default Euclidean norm if the matrix were interpreted as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

The second matrix norm for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is the operator norm given by the linear operator $x \mapsto Ax$, it is naturally induced by the norms you choose for $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$.

These norms are not the same norm, for example the Frobenius norm of the identity matrix $I_n$ is $n$ and its operator norm is $1$.